# Method to return square of a number

Tags: java

I am trying to write a code to return a square of a number

I think my method is basically complete but then I have trouble with compiling,

here is my code

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Number {

    public static void main(String [] args)
    {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter a number to square: ");
        int num = in.nextInt();
        print square(num); //error here, Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
        //print cannot be resolved to a type
        //Syntax error on token "square", = expected after this token
        //at Number.main(Number.java:11)

    }
    public static int square(int num) 
    {
        System.out.println("You entered: " + num);
        num = num * num;
        System.out.println("Your number squared is: " + num);
        return num;

    }
}
```

Comment: You should be using `System.out.println( square(num) );`

Comment: You seem to be familiar with `System.out.println` since you are using it in your `square` method, so why are you trying to write thins as `print square(num);` instead of `System.out.println(square(num));` or simple `square(num);` since all prints are inside this method?

Comment: you accepted my answer. could you please upvote it as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `print square(num);` to `System.out.println(square(num));` or to `square(num);` Although, what you're doing makes no sense because you actually print the number in your method as well. Try changing your code to this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Number {

    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter a number to square: ");
        int num = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Your number squared is: " + square(num));
    }
    public static int square(int num) 
    {
        return num * num;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a `print` statement in Java - you need to use the method `System.out.println(square(num));`

Although, actually, your `square` method is writing the squared number to `STDOUT` anyway, so you don't need to do any more printing - just `square(num);` would be enough.

Answer (score 0):

change:

```
print square(num);
```

for:

```
square(num);
```

you're calling a method, "print" does not make any sense there.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Square {

    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter a number to square: ");
        int num = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Your number squared is: " + square(num));
    }
    public static int square(int num) 
    {
        return num * num;
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).